# Rails 4 Polymorphic Many-to-Many Relationships Needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, rails-activerecord

I am trying to build Nodes and Frames that connect with each other through Links. Nodes can point to an arbitrary number of Nodes and/or Frames. Frames can only receive nodes.

Heres the table structure I am thinking about:

```
Node
    id

Frame
    id

Link
    id
    from_id
    from_type
    to_id
    to_type
```

And here are the associations:

```
Node
    has_many :links, :as => :tos
    has_many :links, :as => :froms

Frame
    has_many :links, :as => :tos

Link
    belongs_to :tos, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :froms, :polymorphic => true
```

Is this the correct approach? From what I'm reading, I'm missing something, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Is there a hierarchical component to this? Do nodes belong to parent nodes etc?

Comment: no hierarchies. but, I'm contemplating making Frame derive from Node and have Link point to Node to simplify things... that might solve the problem..